# Weird numbers shown on Ubuntu 16.04 launcher

Tags: linux, ubuntu, launcher

I am running Ubuntu 16.04. So I was using my computer, and suddenly, some weird numbers showed up in the Ubuntu Launcher. It happened when I tried to close out of VMware Workstation 12.5. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Weird Numbers on Launcher Screenshot]

Comment: They look like keyboard shortcuts, have you got `ALT` or `CTRL` pressed down on the remote machine? I'm not a Linux expert but is there something like Windows Sticky Keys that is going on here?

Comment: @Burgi `ALT` and `CTRL` are both not pressed down.

Comment: @Burgi I finally fixed it. After pressing `CTRL` and `ALT` in the order mentioned, the numbers disappeared.

Comment: That was easy... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have  pressed super key - super key + number/t(like trash bin) starts the application. Potentional answer is here https://askubuntu.com/questions/224536/numbers-on-the-launcher

So I would mark this as duplicate...